# Python autoscroll in gtk textview widget

Tags: python, scroll, widget, gtk

I just have a new project, i just want to learn more about gtk, threads, sockets and classes, so i decided to develop a simple IRC client.

I have some code but i can not find a solution for this:

How do i forbid horizontal scrolling in the textview widget of gtk, and also automatically scroll the textview widget to the bottom?

thanks in advance!

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Pango

class TextViewWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="TinyIRC")

        self.set_default_size(700, 500)

        self.grid = Gtk.Grid()
        self.add(self.grid)

        self.create_chatbox()
        self.create_entry()

    def create_chatbox(self):
        scrolledwindow = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        scrolledwindow.set_hexpand(True)
        scrolledwindow.set_vexpand(True)
        self.grid.attach(scrolledwindow, 0, 1, 3, 1)

        self.textview = Gtk.TextView()
        self.textbuffer = self.textview.get_buffer()
        start_iter = self.textbuffer.get_start_iter()

        self.textbuffer.insert(start_iter, "This is some text ")
        self.textbuffer.insert_markup(self.textbuffer.get_end_iter(), "<b>and some bold text</b>", -1)

        scrolledwindow.add(self.textview)

    def create_entry(self):
        self.entry_box = Gtk.Entry()
        self.grid.attach(self.entry_box, 0, 2 ,3 ,1)
        self.entry_box.connect("activate", self.enter_pressed)

    def enter_pressed(self, widget):
        given_msg=self.entry_box.get_text()
        send_msg=given_msg
        print(given_msg)
        end_iter = self.textbuffer.get_end_iter()
        self.textbuffer.insert(end_iter, send_msg+'\n')
        self.entry_box.set_text("")






win = TextViewWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Changing the horizontal scrolling settings

Using `ScrolledWindow.set_policy()`, you can control whether it scrolls horizontally or not. If you want it not to scroll horizontally, you would add this line right after creating `scrolledwindow`:

```py
scrolledwindow.set_policy(Gtk.PolicyType.NEVER, Gtk.PolicyType.AUTOMATIC)
```

The first argument of `set_policy()` controls the horizontal scrolling, and the second controls the vertical scrolling. Setting the horizontal scrolling to `Gtk.PolicyType.NEVER` makes sure that `scrolledwindow` *never* scrolls horizontally.

#### Scrolling to the end after inserting the text

To scroll to the end after inserting all the text, you can create a mark at the end, and use `textbuffer.scroll_mark_onscreen()` to scroll down to the end. Here is what that would look like:

```py
# Create a mark at the end of all the text
mark = self.textbuffer.create_mark("end", self.textbuffer.get_end_iter(), False)

# Scroll so we can see the end mark
self.textview.scroll_mark_onscreen(mark)
```

### The full code

When we apply these principles to your code, we get something like this (note that I insert much more text so that you can see how the scrolling works):

```py
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Pango

class TextViewWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="TinyIRC")

        self.set_default_size(700, 500)

        self.grid = Gtk.Grid()
        self.add(self.grid)

        self.create_chatbox()
        self.create_entry()

    def create_chatbox(self):
        scrolledwindow = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        
        # Make sure that the window doesn't scroll horizontally
        scrolledwindow.set_policy(Gtk.PolicyType.NEVER, Gtk.PolicyType.AUTOMATIC)

        scrolledwindow.set_hexpand(True)
        scrolledwindow.set_vexpand(True)
        self.grid.attach(scrolledwindow, 0, 1, 3, 1)

        self.textview = Gtk.TextView()
        self.textbuffer = self.textview.get_buffer()
        start_iter = self.textbuffer.get_start_iter()

        self.textbuffer.insert(start_iter, (("This is some text"*10) + "\n")*200)
        end_iter = self.textbuffer.get_end_iter()
        self.textbuffer.insert(end_iter, "This should be the end.")

        scrolledwindow.add(self.textview)

        # Create a mark at the end, and scroll down to it
        mark = self.textbuffer.create_mark("end", self.textbuffer.get_end_iter(), False)
        self.textview.scroll_mark_onscreen(mark)

    def create_entry(self):
        self.entry_box = Gtk.Entry()
        self.grid.attach(self.entry_box, 0, 2 ,3 ,1)
        self.entry_box.connect("activate", self.enter_pressed)

    def enter_pressed(self, widget):
        given_msg=self.entry_box.get_text()
        send_msg=given_msg
        print(given_msg)
        end_iter = self.textbuffer.get_end_iter()
        self.textbuffer.insert(end_iter, send_msg+'\n')
        self.entry_box.set_text("")

win = TextViewWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```